# Cartesian product of object values (to array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let say I have

```
const item = {
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": ["Value2", "Value3"]
}
```

How can I turn it into format as

```
[["Value1","Value2"],["Value1","Value3"]]
```

?

My way of doing is:

```
let array = [];
for (let i of item.Key2){
  array.push([item.Key1,i])
}
```

Just wondering is there any shorter method?

Comment: Why `"Value2"` is inside first element of array.

Comment: Also please share your attempts.

Comment: @MaheerAli Treat it as part of the requirement

Comment: you are looking for a *cartesian product*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// What question mentions
const item = {
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": ["Value2", "Value3"]
}

let res = item.Key2.map(i => [item.Key1, i])
console.log(res)
```

```js
// What the world wants!
const item = {
  "Key1": ["ValueA", "ValueB"],
  "Key2": ["Value1", "Value2"]
}

res = item.Key1.reduce((acc, i1) => acc.concat(item.Key2.map(i2 => [i1, i2])), [])
console.log(res)
```

Comment: The first one would suffice. Second one would be okay but is not necessary, over engineered.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a cartesian product.

```js
const
    item = { Key1: "Value1", Key2: ["Value2", "Value3"] },
    values = Object.values(item).map(v => [].concat(v)),
    result = values.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const item = { Key1: "Value1", Key2: ["Value2", "Value3"]};

let target = item.Key2.reduce((i, _) => {
  i.push([item.Key1, _]);
  return i;
}, []);

console.log(target)
```